# Redirect email using DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record, domain-name

I own a custom domain, i.e myself.com.
I would like to make all email sent to me@myself.com to be delivered to myself@hotmail.com.
I do not want to use Google's Google Apps, or Microsoft's Live Admins.
Is this possible using DNS only?

Comment: What exactly is a "custom" domain? How is myself.com different from any other domain that makes it "custom"?

Comment: It is not. by custom I mean not gmail.com\Hotmail.com. 
this is how it is referred by in Google apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. You can only designate WHICH SERVER handles ALL emails for a domain, nothing else.

You can not rewrite the email, nor forward only specific addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Hotmail *is the same as* Microsoft Live, so you could do this by [setting up custom domains](http://pablodiaz.pro/?p=11) to accept mail via an additional domain, and then create an alias for me@myself.com.  Mail sent to myself@hotmail.com *or* me@myself.com will end up in the same mailbox.

DNS has no part in email redirection.  MX records in DNS just specify which servers handle mail for a given domain.

Answer (score 0):

I use a product from zoneedit.com.  It allows me to manage my DNS and set up custome forwards for all email headed to my domain.  I hand out my me@mydomain.com address to everyone and have zoneedit forward it to gmail.  from there I tell gmail to send the reply-to as the same address.
Zoneedit doe the same for web pages, etc.  Check it out

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, but I thought it was possible w\o third parties. Thanks anyway for the relevant answer.